# how can i deploy my Go app app to heroku using Godep?

Tags: go

I work on windows 32bit and i have a project with golang so how can i deploy it on heroku ?

> my go env  = set GOARCH=386
>   set GOBIN=
>   set GOEXE=.exe
>   set GOHOSTARCH=386
>   set GOHOSTOS=windows
>   set GOOS=windows
>   set GOPATH=C:\Go\bin
>   set GORACE=
>   set GOROOT=C:\Go
>   set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386
>   set GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1
>   set CC=gcc
>   set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
>   set CXX=g++
>   set CGO_ENABLED=1

Comment: Have you tried the heroku documentation? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#introduction

Comment: Consider cross compiling locally with go and uploading the binary to the dyno. I.e. make the dyno run a shell command to start the binary. It's much simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything yet?

If not, try starting with [the tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#introduction). You'll need to install the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) as part of this. Then just follow instructions for pushing your app to Heroku.

Heroku naturally knows how to deploy go apps based on the presence of Godeps/Godeps.json at the root of your repository.

Also make sure your project's `Procfile` contains:

```
web: NAME_OF_YOUR_BINARY
```

For example, if your main is in `$PROJECT/cmd/myapp`, then `Procfile` would be:

```
web: myapp
```